# CSS: How to print (by default) a file with footer (no any classes for it in HTML)

Tags: css, header, footer

How to print a html page with header and footer by default (without explicitly clicking checkboxes during printing)?

For example, for displaying background picture, i found "-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;":

```
.print-layout {
  width: 210mm;
  margin: 0 auto;
  @media print {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}
```

But how to do it for footer and header?
In my HTML page, I don't have any header and footer classes explicitly.Hence in my case,header is name of tab and date, footer is link of site and number of page in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware you cannot get a header and footer added on by just adding css, the new features in HTML allow you to add `<footer>` and `<header>` tags to your HTML and you could add in an `<a>` tag with the URL link to the webpage, again if you need something dynamic like the data changing every time you would have to add in a script with the `new Date()` method.

The -webkit-print-color-adjust property is a non-standard CSS extension which is not really recommended to be used as it does not give reliable outcomes every time.